# Apache Zeppelin & Shiro Authorization

Tags: apache, shiro, apache-zeppelin

I have Apache Shiro up and running just fine. I'm able to block regular users from accessing 'configuration' parameters using the examples given by blocking the Zeppelin API shown below

```
/api/configurations/** = authc, roles[admin]
```

I'm having issues with the Shiro syntax for blocking users from specific URLs or functionality in Apache Zeppelin 0.7.2.

I'd like to block users from seeing the 'Job' section as well as the 'About Zeppelin' modal. The landing screen has links to github, the mailing list, and community which I'd also like to block.

Is this possible using the roles based authorization for [urls] ? For the 'Job' blocking, I've tried ;

`/api/jobmanager/** = authc, roles[admin]`

but it doesn't block 'user1' from seeing the 'Job' section. If it's not possible through Shiro, is there another option? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could u try just /jobmanager without the prefix api?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've tried just about every combination surrounding jobmanager I could. Unfortunately none of them worked.

Comment: `user1` is not supposed to have the `admin` role right? Are you sure that the blocked url has not found a match in some other lines? shiro.ini follows the rule *first matched*: if url1 is defined before url2, any url matching url1 will ignore the rule of url2. Feel free to post the whole `[url]` section if you can